# AEM/Sling - How to create ResourceResolverFactory in a standalone code?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, jcr, sling

I am trying to write some standalone code and not an OSGi bundle for learning and trying out things in AEM. In OSGi bundle I could get the `ResourceResolverFactory` with the `@Reference` annotation.

I am wondering how do I get that in my standalone code. I need this factory to get the `ResourceResolver`. I am not sure if this is even a possibility in the standalone code.

Actually same question goes for another factory, `PageManagerFactory`!

Thanks
- Atul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Refrencing an OSGi service outside of the OSGi environment

That is simply not possible. You need the OSGi runtime to work with OSGi services, period.

In a standalone Java applicaiton, you could technically start the framework in the `main` method of a Java program. Check out the [Apache Felix docs](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html) to see how. But to be honest, I don't see the point of doing so if you're working with AEM. That just makes things more complicated for you. You'd need bundles anyway and you'd be reinventing what AEM already does for you in the first place.

Now, if what you want to do is quickly experiment with some code without the overhead of creating an OSGi bundle, here's a couple of easy ways I know:

## Experimenting with code in AEM

A couple of ways to quicly write code and test it out in AEM without creating a full-blown project.

### AEM Groovy Console

This is an Open Source tool that allows you to execute Groovy code on your AEM instance. It gives you access to the Sling and JCR APIs and also allows you to interact with OSGi services.

It's easy to use, just install it, open the console page, type your script and execute it.

It provides Out Of the Box bindings for a number of commonly used objects, such as the `resourceResolver`, `session`, `pageManager`, `queryBuilder`, `slingRequest` and such.

It also provides a number of convenience methods that make the Sling and JCR APIs easier to use, as well as a very simple utility that allows you to obtain references to OSGi services.

You asked about the `ResourceResolverFactory`, here's how you can get one in a script:

```
def resourceResolverFactory = getService("org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory")
```

The console can even generate this code for you, it has a nice autocomplete feature:

[image: AEM Groovy Console autocomplete of OSGi services]

Check out [the project on GitHub](https://github.com/OlsonDigital/cq-groovy-console) to learn more.

Mind you, the console itself uses a bunch of OSGi bundles so the code is not actually standalone in that it doesn't exist in isolation from the OSGi environment. However, the user does not neeed to create bundles and deploy them just to experiment with the code.

### AEM HTL REPL

Another project you might want to look at is the [AEM HTL REPL](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl). I haven't used it but I know it allows you to use the WCM Use APIs by writing server-side JavaScript.

### Playing around with CRXDE

This is essentionally what [@VAr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709435/1407656) suggests. Create a new component or modify an existing one.

Use a JSP scriptlet or a JavaScript utilising the WCM Use API. You can do it in CRXDE or use an actual IDE to write the code and the [Vault tool](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/core/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html) to upload it to AEM. There are nice plugins for [IntelliJ](https://github.com/shsteimer/IntelliVault) and [Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vaultclipse) that make it somewhat easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a JSP level code snippet the below code snippet will create a page version where this jsp is called. Hope this helps.

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@page import="org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource,
org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver"%>
<% 
PageManager mypageManagerobj = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
Page p= currentPage.getParent(0);
// below line will trigger a version creation process for the current page.
mypageManagerobj.createRevision(p);
%>
```

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to get ResourceResoverl in a standalone java program and not in a jsp or an OSGi bundle. In my OSGi bundle I can get the Factory objects via @Reference annotation. I don't know how to create them in a Java program (with a main).   e.g.

Comment: `@Component(name = "com.cisco.wem.author.rendition.workflow.EOTRenditionPageCreation", specVersion = "1.1", metatype = true)  
@Service  
public class EOTRenditionPageCreation  {  
 @Reference  
 private PageManagerFactory pageMangerFactory;  
 @Reference  
 ResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory;`

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible because the ResourceResolverFactory is part of Apache Sling which is powered by OSGi.

That being said, you should be able to use the [SlingMocks](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html) library which is intended for unit testing. That will allow you to load some sample content from a JSON file and perform operations on the in-memory repository.

FYI: standalone java programs tend to use the JCR APIs to interact with an AEM repository.

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification ! I get the difference between Sling vs. JCR APIs now.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is not possible. `ResourceResolverFactory` is decorated with `@ProviderType` attribute. See 
[ResourceResolverFactory Documentation](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolverFactory.html). The attribute makes the implementations very special for the OSGi framework.

For trying out things in AEM, it is easier to start with AEM boiler plate projects from [AEM Documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/ht-projects-maven.html). OSGi and Sling are too low level and their only real-word values (in context of AEM) lies within servlets and component model bindings.

As a reference, most of the standalone Apache Oak utilities implementation don't use `ResourceResolver` and rather use concrete references for classes (hence imposing strict version compatibility requirements).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resolve and instantiate an OSGI service such as ResourceResolverFactory running a code out of the OSGI environment context. But what you can do is, access the repository and read some nodes (e.g. data) if you want to test something there. For this purpose you can create javax.jcr.Session with the following code:

```
import javax.jcr.Credentials; 
import javax.jcr.Repository; 
import javax.jcr.Session; 
import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials;
org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils;

...

String repoUri = "repo uri", user = "admin", password = "admin";
Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository(repoUri);
Credentials creds = new SimpleCredentials(user, password.toCharArray());
Session session = repository.login(creds);
```